# How can I remove the Job Title and Company from all Address Book contacts using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts

I would like to remove the *Job Title* and *Company* from every contact in my address book using AppleScript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
tell application "Address Book"
    set thePeople to every person
    repeat with i from 1 to length of thePeople
        tell item i of thePeople
            set organization to missing value
            set job title to missing value
        end tell
    end repeat
    save
end tell
```